# How to reunite/merge a face to another in a single object?

Tags: modeling

Hello everyone and happy new year !
In these holidays, I'm making a low-poly chest that looks like this:

[image]

The whole chest is a single object so far. I extruded the central faces along their normals to create the sort of ring in the middle. Right now, as you may see below, the last faces from each side aren't connected to the rest of the chest.

[image]

I found some threads talking about the Knife Project Tool and also the Intersect (Knife) tool, but I think I didn't manage to use the later properly. My other plan was to snap the unconnected face and try to use the Knife tool manually to add the necessary vertex but for reasons that are obscure to me, I was unable to cut from certain edges to another.

I was told multiple times that I have a knack for complicating things but I was wondering if I should, whenever it's possible, keep modelling from a single shape or merge everything together and if so, if you could give me some hints do to so the right way.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and knowledge !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wha i would do is add two cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> the take each points and press <kbd>M</kbd> to merge them *To the last*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why I can't use the knife to cut from a vertex to an edge, the tool behave quite weirdly in this situation. However the "merge at last" seems to did the trick. There is some weird faces left. I'll try to clean this up.
Thanks again !